# Using of xml files in java programming

Tags: java

How to use .xml file in applet coding?
I want to save some context in .xml file in java-applet programming.....
I want to make the changes in that file through coding.
how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, however if you are looking at how to process XML files with Java, then you should probably look at XML APIs for Java, for example [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/).

Tutorial: [A good starting point to learn jdom](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdom/)

Comment: Sample code : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SimpleexampleofusingJDOM.htm scroll down a little and you'll find more examples

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).  It converts between an XML file and a Java object so that you can work with the XML data in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at JAXB (http://jaxb.dev.java.net, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB) which also is a Java to XML binding component. Advantage: JAXB is part of SE version 1.6.